# EF Core column name from mapping api

Tags: entity-framework-core

In EF 6.1 the mapping API was introduced where we could finally get access to table names and column names. Getting the table name is a very nice change in EF Core, but I have not yet uncovered how to get the column names.

For anyone interested here is how I got the table name in the latest version (RC1)

```
context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).SqlServer().TableName
```

What is the current method to get column names or is this not available yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var columnNames = ctx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof (T))
                           .GetProperties().Select(x => x.SqlServer().ColumnName)
                           .ToList();
```

Also

```
var columnNames = ctx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof (T))
                           .GetProperties().Select(x => x.Relational().ColumnName)
                           .ToList();
```

In EF Core 3.X, [`.Relational()` and `.SqlServer()` have been replaced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#provider) and you can simply use:

```
var columnNames = ctx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof (T))
                           .GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetColumnName())
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it would resolve the issue?

Comment: This looks perfect, I'll check this out later tonight and see how it works. By the way I am a fan of the z extensions. :)

Comment: Nice! Did you know I also have a library for entity framework? I'm sure you will become a fan of it also ;)https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus

Comment: Worked perfectly. I didn't realize any of your EF stuff was open source. So commonly people try to wrap everything up and hide the underlying api, I like your style of just extending the objects. That is my preferred approach as well. I ended up doing this to get the property map for something :)

var propertiesMap = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetProperties().ToDictionary(p=>p.Name, p=>p.SqlServer().ColumnName);

Comment: Yup, extending make it very simple to use and you feel like it a part of Entity Framework. I try to open source as much as I can but there is still some part I hide for intellectual property.

Answer (score 3):

This version doesn't assume `SqlServer` and can work as well with `Npgsql` provider as long as data store is relational.

```
var columnNames = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T))
                  .GetProperties().Select(x => x.Relational().ColumnName);
```