# How to get Table Name of mapped entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In some reason, I need to use SQL in EFCore, and I will use table name of mapped entity. How can I get it?

Comment: Seems like this can work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124306/ef7-column-name-from-mapping-api

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Using the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) package in 2.X:

```
var mapping = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(YourEntity)).Relational();
var schema = mapping.Schema;
var tableName = mapping.TableName;
```

This assumes that `dbContext` is a instance of class that inherits from `DbContext` and that you have `YourEntity` configured there.

Note that in EF Core 3.X, [`.Relational()` provider extensions have been replaced] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#provider) with getters and so you can now access the schema as follows:

```
var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(YourEntity));
var schema = entityType.GetSchema();
var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
```

Comment: Does this work for getting all table names? `var modelNames = context.Model.GetEntityTypes();
            foreach (var modelName in modelNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(modelName.Name);
                
            }`

Comment: Also, there's an extension method available for `IEntityType`. So `entityType.GetTableName()`

Comment: There is a new extension method which provides table name prepended by schema name: `entityType.GetSchemaQualifiedTableName()`. It may be useful to create a query manually.

Answer (score 5):

You can Use this static class

```cs
public static class AttributeReader
{
    //Get DB Table Name
    public static string GetTableName<T>(DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        // We need dbcontext to access the models
        var models = context.Model;

        // Get all the entity types information
        var entityTypes = models.GetEntityTypes();

        // T is Name of class
        var entityTypeOfT = entityTypes.First(t => t.ClrType == typeof(T));

        var tableNameAnnotation = entityTypeOfT.GetAnnotation("Relational:TableName");
        var TableName = tableNameAnnotation.Value.ToString();
        return TableName;
    }

}
```

For example, we have Person class that entity name in database is People, we can get people from person class.

```cs
var TblName= AttributeReader.GetTableName<YourModel>(YourContext);
```

Answer (score 4):

#### EF Core 5 version

[EF Core 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes) "now allows an entity type to be mapped to both a table and a view simultaneously".

I don't *fully* understand this, but it adds complications to finding table names.

For my use case I actually wanted the name of a view, so by checking for TableName and ViewName I could throw an error if the entity supplied was for the wrong type.

```
var entityType = typeof(Customer);
var modelEntityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(entityType);

string tableName = modelEntityType.GetSchemaQualifiedTableName();
string viewName = modelEntityType.GetSchemaQualifiedViewName();

if (tableName != null) 
{
   throw new Exception("The Entity " + entityName + " represents a table and not a view");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Simon's answer. In EF Core Version 5x, it is possible to use Microsoft extension methods. Created a `DbContext` helper extension method:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

public static class EfCoreExtensions
{
   public static string GetSchemaQualifiedTableName(this DbContext context, Type entityType)
   {
      IEntityType et = context.Model.FindEntityType(entityType);
      //what to do here, entity could be both view and table!?
      //string viewName = et.GetSchemaQualifiedViewName();
      return et.GetSchemaQualifiedTableName();
   }
}
```

Example of use like this:

```
  string tableName = _dbContext.GetSchemaQualifiedTableName(typeof(SomeEntity));
```

The MS extension methods are housed in the class:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalEntityTypeExtensions
```

Referenced using [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

### DbSet Extension Method to Get Schema Name

Following on from Rax's extension method, you can write an extension method straight off of a DBSet as per below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Schema Table name for the DbSet.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="dbSet"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetTableSchemaName<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
    {
        var context = dbSet.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;
        var entityType = typeof(T);
        var m = context.Model.FindEntityType(entityType);

        return m.GetSchemaQualifiedTableName();
    }
```

Used like this:

```
var context = new SystemContext();
var name = context.SystemTable.GetTableSchemaName();
```