# Truncate table in entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How can I truncate a certain table with C# code, not SQL query?

I want the equivalent of `TRUNCATE TABLE <table_name>`

So far I've tried this:

`context.Products.RemoveRange(context.Products);`

however, it doesnt do anything

Comment: You can't do that with EF. You can, however, use a SQL query in the context, like `context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("Truncate table <table_name>");`

Comment: BTW, `RemoveRange` should work (but it doesn't truncate the table, it will use `delete` for each matching row), have you use a `context.SaveChanges()` afterwards?

Comment: @Magnetron you're right...I totally forgot about saving the changes. it works now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, that's not what an ORM is for.

An ORM helps you access the database in terms of object access. Truncating a table is a data layer operation, not an object operation. The equivalent in Entity Framework would be to load all objects from the database and delete them one by one.

You don't want that, you want to truncate the table. Then dive down into SQL and truncate that table.

Surely there are extensions on Entity Framework that allow things like this, but in the end they will generate exactly the SQL you're preventing to execute, so why not simply do that yourself?

Comment: Thank you. Was just wondering if I missed something in the docs. I will use ExecuteSqlRaw then for these kinds of needs. Thank you!

Comment: Ok answer because it's true, you need to do it yourself. Except I don't think I've ever read anything that said an ORM shouldn't allow truncate, it just so happens that Hibernate and Entity Framework (maybe others?). I guess I'll find out when I need it - but I wouldn't take what exists today as dogma. Thankfully truncate is standard, even though it's implementation is not (e.g. in SQL Server you can do a transaction and roll back, with oracle, it's gone, etc. etc..) as far as what I'd want an ORM to do, I really never cared because it's all arbitrary based on what the devs want.

Comment: @Dan it's because an Object-Relational Mapper (ORM)'s entire premise and promise are that you can access your _data_ through _objects_. Clearing the underlying storage (as opposed to deleting the objects one by one) would require you to drop down into storage specifics, like `ExecuteSQL("TRUNCATE ...")`, which is exactly what I try to convey in my answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not disagreeing with you really, but maybe it has more to do with why people use Truncate to begin with. They usually want to clear their data, but technically, as you said, it's deeper than that. We run into the same issues when we give permissions, SQL Server requires DDL for Truncate and considers it a structural change to the table. Perhaps the real answer is long gone, which would have been a SQL standard command that says "Clear all of the data", then perhaps it'd fit better?

Comment: @Dan I've not come across a situation myself where I'd need it. Removing a handful of records is common, and not really a (performance) problem when done by ORM. I can't imagine a common application use case where you'd need to clear an entire table. And I think the people out there designing ORM solutions thought the same.

Comment: @CodeCaster probably, the only time I've ever needed it is when loading a daily table with data, clear and reload each night. You could load then remove yesterday's data, but if there's a lot it's better just to truncate first. Maybe a stored procedure then. Truncate has also helped me if you have enough records that you don't want transaction logs to hurt the DB. When cleaning up a major mess, if you have Disaster Recovery,  you truncate instead of delete to avoid shipping the delete logs to the other system, you just truncate in both. Moderators are going to get mad at convo, have a good one

Comment: @CodeCaster Clear and reload is what led me to this particular SO page actually, I've already scaffolded the whole thing with EF6 and was hoping I could just go .truncate(), would have been nice in a "I don't care about the details just give me results" kind of corporate world we're in.

Answer (score 5):

I have done things as below, for EF Core 5.0.11
This is working for SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL

```
public class AnnotationHelper
{
    /*
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667126/how-to-get-table-name-of-mapped-entity-in-entity-framework-core
     */
    private static string GetName(IEntityType entityType, string defaultSchemaName = "dbo")
    {
        //var schemaName = entityType.GetSchema();
        //var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
        var schema = entityType.FindAnnotation("Relational:Schema").Value;
        string tableName = entityType.GetAnnotation("Relational:TableName").Value.ToString();
        string schemaName = schema == null ? defaultSchemaName : schema.ToString();
        string name = string.Format("[{0}].[{1}]", schemaName, tableName);
        return name;

    }

    public static string TableName<T>(DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
    {
        var entityType = dbSet.EntityType;
        return GetName(entityType);
    }
}
 

public static class EfHelper
{
    /*
     * need to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
     */
    public static string Truncate<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
    {
        var context = dbSet.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;
        string cmd = $"TRUNCATE TABLE {AnnotationHelper.TableName(dbSet)}";        
        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
            }
            command.CommandText = cmd;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return cmd;
    }
}


[Test]
public void Truncate()
{
    Db.Users.Add(new User() 
    {
        Name = "Name",
        Email = "Email",
        CreatedBy = "CreatedBy",
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
    });
    Db.SaveChanges();
    Assert.GreaterOrEqual(Db.Users.ToList().Count, 1);

    /*Truncate table*/
    Db.Users.Truncate();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, Db.Users.ToList().Count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

re: extensions as mentioned by CodeCaster: If you are allowed to use NUGET packages in your code, you might find this library useful; it has 'Truncate' and 'TruncateAsync' exactly as you've asked about.

https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Yes, behind the scenes it is still using 'ExecuteSqlRaw', but using a c# method allows better error handling.  For example, in some cases database security may not allow table truncation by the executing thread, so if that's important to your application you can handle it easier with a wrapper.

Comment: is that nuget paid? Can we use truncate without paying?