# SQL Server functions in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I am converting this query from a stored procedure to C#:

```
INSERT mytable WITH (ROWLOCK) (created_by, date_started)
VALUES (USER_NAME(), GETDATE())
```

I couldn't find a way to have EF Core generate SQL functions like `USER_NAME()` and `GETDATE`, so I am added 2 functions to the `DbContext`:

```
public async Task<DateTime> GetDatabaseDateTimeAsync()
{
    var dateTimeParameter = new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    await Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("SELECT @date = GETDATE()",dateTimeParameter);
    DateTime.TryParse( dateTimeParameter.Value.ToString(), out var returnDateTime);
    return returnDateTime;
}

public async Task<string> GetDatabaseUserAsync()
{
    var userNameParameter = new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar,30) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    await Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("SELECT @user = USER_NAME()",userNameParameter);
    return userNameParameter.Value.ToString();
}
```

And I'm calling them like this:

```
var mytable = new MyTable
                  {
                      CreatedBy = await _dbContext.GetDatabaseUserAsync(),
                      DateStarted = await _dbContext.GetDatabaseDateTimeAsync()
                  };

_dbContext.MyTable.Add(mytable);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This results in 2 extra SELECTs - is there a better way to do it?

Comment: using orm meant giving up some power of the raw sql for convenience. some sql functions have ef equivalent, `GETDATE()` is equivalent to `DateTime.Now` not sure about `USER_NAME` gotta dig github first.

Comment: also, you have the option to map the db procedure to ef. much simpler rather than translating everything to ef.

Comment: `GETDATE()` is `DateTime.Now()`, unless your C# application machine and DB machine have time difference. As for `CreatedBy`, it depends on your database structure, but doesn't `USER_NAME()` returns schema name like `dbo`?

Comment: I tried using DateTime.Now(), checked the generated query in the profiler, it had a date value instead of `GETDATE()`, client and db server are on the same time zone, need experimenting to verify this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct USER_NAME() is returning dbo

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45671666/16606026) for getting schema name. You can get it once everytime application starts up to save time and resources. Still this looks wrong as every user creating data through your C# project will be marked as `dbo`. Maybe a good time to re-check the requirements.

Comment: yeah just converting old store proc to C# EF. something is not right in the logic